# Android listview item update every time it is scroll back into screen

Tags: android, listview, random

I have a `listView` which has its content as random generated numbers. If one item in the `listView` is scrolled out of the screen and then scrolled back in, the random generated number is changed (it generates a new number).

Is there any way I can prevent this from happening?

A example code is [here](https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src/c6aa6d346f37/Examples/DemoApp/src/com/androidplot/demos/ListViewActivity.java?at=master)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this code for listview implement listener and/or your getview() method calling every time on scroll up and/or down,

```
mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // write down your code here
            // i think notifyDataSetChanged() this method calling whatever u require.
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, 
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // write down your code here
        }
    }); // mListView.setOnScrollListener close
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because every time your item goes off the screen and again come to front it calls getview() method. To solve this you can store all random generated numbers in an array in starting and use it to show the items.
OR
i think using view holder class (i didn't try).